# How to make same attribute work for both ApiController and Controller classes?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I need some logic to be executed before action execution. The problem is that I have both `ApiController` and `Controller` classes.

I've tried to use common for both `System.Attribute` but `override Match()` will not execute. Any Ideas ?

Comment: Make two attributes, abstract their shared logic into another component (a method or class both attributes use).

Comment: You can't use single attribute for 2 different type of controllers, but you can put shared logic inside a class, then make sure that different attributes inherit from that class.